# Loop through a list and get an elements image id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#newsImageGallery li').each(function() { 
    alert($(this));
});
```

In each of my li I have an image with an id, how can I alert that images id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#newsImageGallery li').each(function() { 
    alert($(this).find("img").attr("id"));
});
```

or of course, without the find:

```
$('#newsImageGallery li img').each(function() { 
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

And as Pointy mentions underneath, if you use jQuery 1.6+ you're better off using .prop instead of .attr:

```
$('#newsImageGallery li img').each(function() { 
    alert($(this).prop("id"));
});
```

Comment: Better to use `.prop("id")` instead of `.attr()` as the "id" really is a property of the image DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert( $(this).find('img').attr('id') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#newsImageGallery li').each(function() { 
    alert($(this).find('img').attr('id'));
});
```